# pytest and coverage combination does not work

Tags: python, code-coverage, pytest

I installed plugin for pytest from here:http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-cov. Then I have a simple test code:

pytest.py:

```
class TestNumbers:
    def test_int_float(self):
        assert 1 == 1.0

    def test_int_str(self):
        assert 1 == 1
```

I tried to test it with command: `py.test --cov-report term --cov pytest.py`. But it doesn't work. Even if I gave the entire absolute path of pytest.py it was still no data for collecting. However if I use `py.test pytest.py`, surely it tested Ok.

I am very confusing about this problem, thanks for help.

Comment: use a filename prefixed "test_" but in any case don't use "pytest.py" which will shadow the actual "pytest" module.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
py.test --cov-report term --cov=. test.py
```

The `--cov` parameter takes an argument saying which paths to cover.  In your example, `--cov` would consume `test.py`, but then there were no arguments left for py.test about which files to test.

**UPDATE**: as @hpk42 points out, you need to call your example something other than `pytest.py`.  When I did this locally, I called it `test.py` instead.

Comment: If "pytest.py" is the user-module, it will not work.  It shadows the the actual py.test (because you do "import pytest" to import helpers/things).

Comment: Whups... that was meant to be `test.py` in my example.  You're absolutely right of course.  `py.test` does at least output a decent error message informing you of this problem though.

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem is that used 'pytest.py' as filename. After change it all tests went through Ok. You answer is right. Command should be "py.test --cov-report term --cov=. test.py"

Comment: If anybody's wondering how to get coverage numbers from doctests  (A coworker of mine thought this wasn't supported) --

`$ py.test --doctest-modules . --cov-report term --cov=.` or 
`$ py.test --doctest-modules mymodule --cov-report term --cov=mymodule`